# Collection.sort(arraylist) in a function sorting another arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

say, I made an arraylist in (public class class1(String args[]))

```
static List<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

then I pass this arraylist to a function in (public static void main(String args[]))

```
biggestvalue(list1);
```

this is the function for example:

```
public static double biggestvalue(List<Double> list){
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list.get(list.size()-1);
}
```

I pass it into a function so that hopefully it will only sort list but not list1, but then list1 gets sorted as well, and I do not understand why that is.
Therefore, please explain to me why that is, and what solutions to this error are out there?

Comment: In any case: **Do NOT sort a list to obtain the "biggest value"**. That's what `Collections.max(collection)` is for!

Comment: @Marco13 thank you for the information, i am now one step away from stop being a nub:) anyway it's just an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only pass a reference to the `List` when you pass it as an argument. Therefore, both `list` and `list1` point to the same `List`.

A good rule of thumb is to not modify objects passed into a method, so I would make a copy inside the method:

```
public static double biggestvalue(List<Double> list){
    List<Double> temp = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(temp);
    return temp.get(temp.size()-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`list1` gets sorted as well because you are passing a reference to that object. You want to duplicate the list before sorting it, so the original object doesn't get modified:

```
List<Double> dup = new ArrayList<>(list);
Collections.sort(dup);
return dup.get(dup.size() - 1);
```